# How does food work in Ultima VII?

Tags: ultima-7

I've been playing *[Ultima VII: The Black Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_VII:_The_Black_Gate)* and after a while, Iolo starts complaining every five seconds about being hungry. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to feed him. I tried picking up food and dragging it to him, but that just resulted in it being placed in his inventory.

How do I feed my party members? Do I need to feed myself? Can I tell how hungry we are or do we have to just rely on the complaining?

In short, how does food work in *Ultima VII*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Base Game

**Double click the food item** and a reticule will come up. Just like using potions or bandages. Then click on someone with it.

### Exult (*highly* recommended!)

Assuming you're running [Exult](http://exult.sourceforge.net), **just press 'F'** and a reticule will appear having selected a (?) random (?) food item from your party's storage. *

Also in Exult, 'K' will try every key you have. 'P' will use a lock pick.

You can see if **they're hungry if they have a picture of a knife and fork** at the bottom of their character sheet.

* Using 'F' seems to use as many items as necessary to fill them up, as IME, they always say they're full if I try to feed them again, but that could be because I always carry a sack completely full of venison.

Comment: I'm running the GOG.com release of Ultima VII, not Exult. Does the `F` key work in that release? Also, once the reticule comes up, I'm guessing I click on a party member to feed? I've never had to use potions or bandages yet, so I'm not sure how those work either.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I'd assume you can get Exult to work with the GoG release (*highly* recommended!). [In the original](https://www.gog.com/forum/ultima_series/ultima_vii_a_starting_guide/post7) only A,C,H,I,S, and Z are hot keys, along with ESC and ALT-X. - Yep, you have to click on somebody with it. With potions, don't miss, or you'll waste it. FYI, w/ or w/o Exult you can DB click a stack of coins to close all inventory screens.